# Linux Shell/Bash THEN section in IF statement somehow get's triggered

Tags: bash, shell

I have a THEN section that updates a variable from within a loop, the variable prints correctly but then it seems like the IF condition still equals to true as the THEN section is triggered in every loop. I'm a little confused by this as the IF statement

```
#!/bin/bash

highscore=0
for i in {1..5}
do
   dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
   lastEntry=$(perl -ne '/(Score: \d+)/ && print "$1\n";' scorelist.txt | tail -1 | awk  '{print $2}')
   highestEntry=$(perl -ne '/(Score: \d+)/ && print "$1\n";' scorelist.txt | sort | tail -1 | awk  '{print $2}')
   
   echo $dt
   echo "Round: $i"
   echo "Your score: $lastEntry"
   echo "Highscore:  $highscore"
   
   if [ $highestEntry > $highscore ]
   then
     echo $highscore
     highscore=$highestEntry
     echo $highscore
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

The scorelist is a simple text file:

```
Score: 15
Score: 13
Score: 18
Score: 12
Score: 16
Score: 15
Score: 10
```

Since the IF statement basically says `if [ 18 > 18 ]` I don't understand why the THEN section get's triggered every round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the IF statement basically says if [ 18 > 18 ] I don't understand why the THEN section get's triggered every round

Because `>` is a redirection operator even here, not a comparison operator.

The condition of shell 'if' statements follows the same syntax as regular commands. It's always worth remembering that the real syntax is `if CMD; then CMD...; fi`, and that `[` is just a weird-looking command, *not* a real syntax element.

So what you have is equal to `[ 18 ] > 18`, which checks something entirely different – it checks whether the string "18" is non-empty, which indeed succeeds (while redirecting the command's output to a file also named "18"). You probably have a bunch of empty files with numeric names after this.

Although `[` (and `[[`) *can* compare numbers, the real operators are **`-gt` and `-lt`**, not `< >`. For example, `[ $aa -gt $bb ]`.

Only `((` and `[[` operators have a special exception; `(( a > b ))` would indeed compare the variables numerically.

So the correct options would be any of:

- `[ $aa -gt $bb ]` – standard in all sh-like shells;
- `[[ $aa -gt $bb ]]` – Bash/ksh(/zsh?) only;
- `(( aa > bb ))` – Bash/ksh(/zsh?) only but supports arithmetic expressions; recommended if you write for /bin/bash;
- `test $aa -gt $bb` – a synonym for `[`; rarely used in scripts but might make it easier to understand how 'if' conditions actually work (`if test foo; then..`);
- ***Not** `[[ $aa > $bb ]]` – although this doesn't invoke redirection, it actually checks lexical ordering (i.e. sorting the strings alphabetically), not a numeric comparison like `-gt`.*

Answer (score 1):

```
if (( $highestEntry > $highscore ))
```

should do the trick. See [BASH manual](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bash/bash.1.en.html#Compound_Commands), for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`$ man bash`

type `/COND`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, scroll down to find...

```
string1 > string2
          True if string1 sorts after string2 lexicographically.
```

NOTE: Not compared as NUMBERS.

just below it you find...

```
  arg1 OP arg2
          OP  is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than
          or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to arg2, respectively.  Arg1 and arg2 may be positive or negative integers.  When used  with  the
          [[ command, Arg1 and Arg2 are evaluated as arithmetic expressions  (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION above).
```

... telling to use `-gt` for numerical values.

---

[www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) -> Bash guides - will tell you more detail...